# Make linux obtain IP when router becomes available

Tags: networking

I have a headless PC - as such I cant see what's going on inside until I connect with its IP and login to the machine. I have this PC connected over Ethernet to a router with DHCP. Problem is, I fail to turn on the router "*and make it in ready state*" prior to booting the PC. When PC completes booting prior to router becoming available, PC fails to get a known IP address and Im unable to ping it with any of the IP address within range of the router's DHCP server and as such I end up having a proper headless PC :) with no clue of why it failed to connect to the network.

**How can I make the PC obtain an IP address as soon as the DHCP router becomes available ?**

Comment: You could give it a static IP address.

Comment: Pls tell me how. I have played around with /etc/network/interfaces but that was for the same issue using wifi. But I gave up on wifi and now want to work on Ethernet. My interfaces file doesn't have anything (I commented out all my previous changes)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there it is documented how to configure a static IP on whatever OS you are running on your PC.

Comment: Even if I give a static IP, will it still be able to "own it" and be addressable after the router has become available ?

Comment: You should assign the static IP outside of your DHCP address pool so that there won't be address conflicts with other devices. The address must be in the same subnet as other devices. And yes, once the device has a static IP address, it is always available with that IP address.

Comment: My question is not about static routes, but rather, is linux able to "discover" and connect to the router once the router becomes avlbl ? Will that happen automatically for ethernet connections ? And how about if I have static route for WiFi as well - will it be able to connect automatically to the router over wifi ? The PC being headless makes it important to query router availability and connect regardless of which interface is used. - thanks