# Would a static IP make PC go online as soon as router become available/ready?

Tags: networking, dhcp, linux-networking, static-ip, headless

I have posted a part of this question [here](https://serverfault.com/q/842168/236342) and now what Im questioning is an answer suggested - *to create a static IP*. **Question in short:** I have a headless PC(running Ubuntu) and I want to make this go online as soon as the router becomes available. In a case where I start the PC first and the router isn't available at PC's bootup (and the router becomes available later) I've seen that Im unable to query the PC from any of the IPs in the DHCP pool. However if the router was started earlier, then any of the first few IPs in the DHCP pool should give me a hit to the headless PC and Im able to SSH into it.

After creating a static IP in the `interfaces` file and also adding the line `auto eth0` (which was surprisingly missing) and other network stuff, I was able to create a static IP and it works well - now I know for certain if the headless PC is on the network or not with ONE IP.

However in the case where the **router is brought up later, would the PC still be able to go online using the static IP ?**

Comment: Please clarify "to go online". What exactly is meant with that?

Comment: "to go online" I should be able to ping that from the other side of the network. Or better yet, I should be able to login thru SSH using the static IP.

Comment: Yes, if the router is up, it will forward all packets via the networks it is configured to be in.

Comment: Problem is router comes up late, after the PC has finished booting.

Comment: Well, if there is no router up, then the PC has no connectivity if routing happens via that router.

Comment: Pls read the question - it says router comes up late. So when PC has finished booting, it finds no router. Im asking, if the router is not available at the time when PC is booting, does that mean PC is not addressable thereafter even if router becomes available later ? Tell me, why is this question so difficult to comprehend ??

Comment: I answered already in the third comment. With static addressing, there is no such thing as "PC finding out if there is no router". Layer 3 in IP networking is stateless, every IP packet not in its own subnetwork is sent as is to the default gateway.